# Snow Leopard Server - VPN server - the ppp server could not be authenticated error

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

I have a snow leopard server configured for vpn access with l2tp over ipsec and it has been working fine for a number of months and now it has stopped working and I can't seem to find what is wrong.

I get this error on the client side

```
the ppp server could not be authenticated
```

The logs on the server look like this

```
<password hash>, name = "alex"]
Tue Aug 17 15:38:17 2010 : sent [CHAP Success id=0x56 "S=hash M=Access granted"]
Tue Aug 17 15:38:17 2010 : rcvd [CHAP Response id=0x56
```

Thanks, Alex

Comment: adding noauth to the pppd options file should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue.  Server works for a month or so, then all of a sudden get a message "VPN Connection the PPP Server could not be authenticated".  I can see the connection being opened on the server log, but the it's disconnected.  Did did a time machine restore yesterday and everything went back to normal...  now today we have the same issue.  Very annoying, any ideas?

Comment: Not yet, will let you know if I get a solution

Comment: was on the phone w/ apple tech for a few hours.  he looked at the setup, apparently the dns was not setup properly and the ldap coudln't communicate properly w/ the server.  So we did a clean install and he walked through the whole thing to make sure everything was proper..  more than i wished to do, but it works now.  let me know if you found a solution and a reason for this problem. thanks - eric